# Fetch bookmark from the database on the basis of tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I am new in Rails, I have 3 models in the application namely Bookmark, Tag, Tagging. I want to fetch all the bookmark on the basis of tag.

Attributes of the model are:

Bookmark: id , name

Tag : id , name

Tagging : bookmark_id , tag_id

Association between models:

bookmark.rb

```
has_many :taggings
has_many :tags, through: :taggings
```

tag.rb

```
has_many :taggings
has_many :bookmarks, through: :taggings
```

tagging.rb

```
belongs_to :tag
belongs_to :bookmark
```

The solution to fetch bookmark is :

```
Tag.find(id).bookmarks
```

but their is one problem with this is in this case i can search the bookmark on the basis of one tag only but i want to search on the basis of multiple tag. How can i implement that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have all your associations set up (ex. `has_many :bookmarks, :through => :taggings` on your `Tag` class, or whichever associations make the most sense based on what bookmarks and tags are), you should be able to call `#bookmarks` on any instance of `Tag`.  Ex. `Tag.find(1).bookmarks` will return all bookmarks paired with that tag in the tagging join table.

I would start by reading http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html if you haven't yet.  Then check out http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html, which shows you how to use `ActiveRecord::QueryMethods` and the SQL they generate.

Edit based on your follow-up question:

Say you have an array of three tag ids:

```
tag_ids = [1, 2, 3]
tags = Tag.find(tag_ids)
tags.map(&:bookmarks)
```

If you want a query that is more flexible, you could do something like:

```
Tag.where("tags.id IN (?)", tag_ids).joins(:taggings => :bookmark)
```

Now, if you wanted only bookmarks created within the last month, you could do:

```
Tag.where("tags.id IN (?)", tag_ids).joins(:taggings => :bookmark).where("bookmarks.created_at >= ?", 1.month.ago)
```

Look into scopes and / or class methods, which you can use to encapsulate queries and make them chainable to get a lot of flexibility.  Hope this helps.

Comment: i have mentioned my association above.

Comment: The answer that you have given in this case we can access the bookmark on the basis of one tag but in my case tags may be multiple so how i can implement this?

Comment: Thanks for adding the associations code.  To clarify- you mean if you have a collection of 10 tags, how to get all the bookmarks associated with those 10 tags?  If, for example, each tag is associated with 10 bookmarks, you want a query to return all 100 bookmarks?

Comment: yeah exactly. Suppose i have search for ruby, rails, programming so in this case i want all the bookmark that is associated with all the three tags not a single tag.

Comment: You don't need to start with tag ids, I was just using that as an example (since a form might pass in an array of selected ids).  If you have tag names, you should be able to do the same thing with an array of names: `Tag.where("tags.name IN (?)", tag_names)`.  There are multiple ways of achieving this, so you really should read the second guide I linked to in my answer.